# why there is a need to have voice - ad hoc network in inter vehicle communication system rather than using a "typical radio transmitter & receiver"

Tags: radio, network-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to ad hoc networking mode using WiFi in vehicles](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22163/how-to-ad-hoc-networking-mode-using-wifi-in-vehicles)

We are making inter-vehicle communication system. So, we are looking at using WiFi Ad-Hoc networking mode (with no external infrastructure needed except what ever is in the vehicle).. 
[ we are looking to transmit Voice. Voice-over ad hoc network mode using Wifi ]
- how it is possible to do. Please mention what exactly we require to build a system like this.

Secondly.
One of my colleague raised a question : Why can't we use a typical radio transmitter & receiver..  i.e., put a radio transmitter & receiver  in every vehicle. so, who ever is in your close vicinity gets connected..

Why do we need something more complicated device mentioned previously.

Comment: @starblue See the other gazillion questions on the same topic that have been posted over the past 24 hours...

Comment: And in answer to your second question - if you can't answer it yourself why are you even considering starting the project?

Comment: What is the context of this project? Commercial? Student? Hobby? Something else?

Comment: This is getting tiresome.  You've asked a bunch of similar questions, people have spent time and effort answering them, yet you come back with more of the same.  Time close.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that the the physical range and communications reliability offered by peer to peer WiFi is NOT adequate for your purposes.
 **IF** it is  then it has the advantages of

- Being acceptable to regulatory authorities for operation in a consistent and relatively seamless manner in most (but not all) countries.
- Offering potentially good security against access and interception.
- Good end to end security and assurance of reliable information transfer.
- Ease of provision of high level control functionality "programmatically"
- Being already tightly integrated with major operating systems and not requiring the construction of a multi layer model as would be the case if attempts were made to computer-control radio transceivers "from the ground up".

If all you want is "CB" (Citizen's band) type multi station audio  intercommunication, then there are many existing systems that meet this need cheaply or well and possibly both.

If however you want a communication scheme that is able to be tightly integrated with a computing, and feature rich [tm] data oriented processing and transfer then a WiFi based solution may be a good starting point.  However, the effort required to make it more than a multidrop digital walkie talkie system may be very significant.

If more than a small amount of the above is news to you then you should probably be looking at buying an existing system.